# BLoC search debounce

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I have a bloc (piece of code)

```
    ...
  Stream<SearchState> _mapSearchSuggestionsEvent(SearchSuggestionsEvent event) async* {
    final results = await _searchApi.getSuggestions(event.query);
    yield SearchStateShowSuggestions(results);
  }
    ...
```

and tried to debounce events to avoid excessive network calls

```
  @override
  Stream<Transition<SearchEvent, SearchState>> transformEvents(
      Stream<SearchEvent> events, TransitionFunction<SearchEvent, SearchState> transitionFn) {
    return events.debounceTime(Duration(milliseconds: 1000)).asyncExpand(transitionFn);
  }
```

Also I added logs inside `_searchApi.getSuggestions` method.

What I see in logs :

```
I/flutter ( 4838):  [SearchApi] : getSuggestions
I/flutter ( 4838):  [SearchApi] : getSuggestions k
I/flutter ( 4838):  [SearchApi] : getSuggestions kr
I/flutter ( 4838):  [SearchApi] : getSuggestions kre
I/flutter ( 4838):  [SearchApi] : getSuggestions krev
I/flutter ( 4838):  [SearchApi] : getSuggestions kreve
```

and so on...

Adding event :

```
_textEditingController.addListener(() {
      _bloc.add(SearchSuggestionsEvent(_textEditingController.text));
    });
```

Maybe I don't understand, but why my calls is not skipping when I'm using debounce?

Comment: @pskink I call `add` every time when the query has changed

Answer (score -1):

This is a code example from the official documentation:

```
@override
Stream<Transition<PostEvent, PostState>> transformEvents(
  Stream<PostEvent> events,
  TransitionFunction<PostEvent, PostState> transitionFn,
) {
  return super.transformEvents(
    events.debounceTime(const Duration(milliseconds: 500)),
    transitionFn,
  );
}
```

Please, double-check if that works in your case. Not sure, but maybe `asyncExpand` just delays your events but they are not skipped, meaning you still send a request for each input change. Source: https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterinfinitelisttutorial

Comment: Unfortunately this not work (even if it copied from original doc).

Comment: Not sure, but I've used this pattern for infinity load, works like a charm: https://github.com/mkobuolys/shopping-app-prototype/blob/main/lib/modules/products/bloc/products_bloc.dart